# Mysql databases never found

Tags: mysql, spring, database, express, database-connection

I'm using Wamp64 for mySql. The problem is that I cannot access any of my databases from a backend.
I tried connecting to a database with Spring and it said that it didn't exist, but I checked multiple times and the database was there. I also tried with other newly created databases.
Now I'm building a backend in Express and I have the same identical problem. My databases look like they don't exist.
One thing to notice is that the connection works well with default databases, like 'information_schema' and 'mysql'. Here's some code if you want to check.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "gestionesemine",
  multipleStatements: true
});

connection.connect((err)=>{
  if (!err) {
    console.log("Connesso al database");
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| disneyland         |
| gestionesemine     |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that the problem was that it was trying to connect to MariaDB, that comes with Wamp64, so it was accessing those databases instead of the ones I had in mySql. I still don't know why. Anyway my solution is simply specifying the port:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  port : 3308,
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'gestionesemine',
  multipleStatements: true
});
```